# use jQuery .on() parsing multiple events will cause performance issues?

Tags: jquery

On the case of form validation through jQuery, I've been reading and found out that using a .keyup() handler won't allways work as expected. For instance, this event alone doesn't work on my Android (gingerbread) and doesnt cover the possible paste or autocomplete the user may perform on the input. Instead, using `.on('input keyup change', '#selector', function(){})` seems to be the best choice. Will jQuery perforperform the event only once in case more than one of the binded events gets executed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w84boeq7/1/ - see for each key press the up and input events are fired so it is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/eyxb7973/1/

It will cause performance issues yes, if you try to type something in the field, you will see that `input` and `keyup` are fired.